# complex number in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, complex-numbers

Can I directly use complex number in Objective-C? Which is like complex double b=3+5*I, a=sqrt(b). Or I have to build my own class about the operating methods?

Comment: Why don't you just use C99's complex types?

Comment: I use that which is like complex double parameter = 3+4*I, but when I sqrt a negative number it does not give the right answer(e.g. cimag(sort(3+4*I)) is supposed to be a complex number, but it only calculates the sort(3) which is 1.732+0.00*I). why?